# No more logs all of a sudden, no settings or config changed

Tags: arangodb, arangojs

I have been catching logs until two days ago and now all of a sudden I do not see any logs. I didnt touch the command line. I just have updated the only service I have to save documents in the database.

**Arangodb Version. 3.1.6
environment Ubuntu 14.04 / Nginx**

**Problem:**
No logs at all.
Screenshot attached.

**I tried:**
Nothing has changed in the server, in terms of updates, settings, configs or anything. If I go to /var/log/arangod/arangod.log - it says file not found.

Any direction or help would be highly appreciated.

[https://gifyu.com/image/MALB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p29sA.png)

Comment: Have you restarted the server? Have you tried to update to the latest version of ArangoDB?

Comment: David you yes restarted brought the logs back - awesome Thanks alottttt... its a bug so to avoid future restart I will update the version :) Appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is an issue with the web interface's log output in the 3.1 branch. It was fixed in the 3.2 branches and releases, but for 3.1 it has not been fixed as of version 3.1.27.

A pull request with a fix for the 3.1 branch is here: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/pull/3563

Comment: Awesome, Thanks I just upgraded to fix the bug.

Comment: Please note that the PR has not been merged into the 3.1 branch yet. And it is not yet part of any 3.1 release. That means until it is merged and a new 3.1 release is built, the fix is usable only if you compile ArangoDB yourself from source.